# How do I use Powershell to detach a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am sure that this can be achieved by loading the [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) assemblies but I am curious as to whether the 'Start Powershell' item in the context menu within SQL Server Management Studio 2008 will give me a headstart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMO Server class has a DetachDatabase method that you can use from Start PowerShell. From the server level in sqlps you can use something like this:

PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\Z002>get-childitem | foreach{$_.DetachDatabase("pubs",$false)}

See the [MSDN docs for detailed info on DetachDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210177.aspx):

Comment: Your answer tells me that the SQL Server is implemented as a PSDrive which pretty much answers my question. I would however be interested in understanding why you needed a 'foreach' here.

Comment: Get-childitem when run at the machine level will return all the SQL instances on the server. If you have multiple instances foreach would be neeed. Probably doesn't make sense in this case though. But I have multiple on the machine I ran command on. If just one instance you could either assign the Server object to a variable or do something like this:

(get-childitem ).DetachDatabase("pubs",$false)

OR assign server object to variable

$server = get-childitem
$server.DetachDatabase("pubs",$false)